# Redirect to page before login

Tags: rules, sessions

Now i know there are some ways that a redirect on login can be setup, ie using views etc, but i think my issue maybe a bit more complicated.

When a user accesses a node for example where they are prompted to login, from here they are directed over to the /user/login page.

I want the user to be redirected back to the page they were before they came to the /user/login page, with a few exceptions of course.

How can i get the user journey to be...Node -> user/login -> redirect back to Node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways to do this (if you are able to build the links manually) is to add the destination parameter to the URL.

/user/login?destination=node/xxxx

After login, you will automatically be redirected to node/xxxx.

Comment: I think you are along the right lines here, the only problem is my /user/login pages are setup using FPP and so cannot use a token for each referring node.

Answer (score 1):

There is a module that takes care of this called [Login Destination](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_destination).

> The Login Destination module allows you to customize the destination
>   that a user is redirected to after logging in, registering to the site
>   (7.x), using a one-time login link or logging out (7.x). The
>   destination can be an internal page or an external URL. It is possible
>   to specify certain conditions like referring pages or user roles and
>   make the destination depend upon them. You may use PHP snippets to
>   provide custom conditions and destinations. It is also possible to
>   keep users on the currently visited page after logging in or out.

Also available for Drupal 8[image: Login Destination (D8)]

Comment: Have tried this module but doesn't seem like it works to what i need it for

Comment: @Key I'm not sure how you are redirecting users to the login page in the first place, but you can probably replace that process with [r4032login](https://www.drupal.org/project/r4032login) which will take care of both redirects.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way with Rules:

Event - Drupal initialize

Condition - site current user does not have a role authenticated
Condition - site current page url does not contain 'user/'

Action - Site-redirect to user/login, append original destination.

Not the most efficient of ways, but no coding is required.

Comment: Tried setting this up but have realised this is not what i am after, this forces anonymous using to the login page.